# Pass current instance of class to a newly created one

Tags: java, class, instance

So I have a class A which needs to create an instance of class B in some cases. If this happens class B needs to be able to call methods of the instance of class A which created it.

How can I achieve this in the best way possible in Java? Can I pass the current instance of the class to the second one I am creating so I can access the methods of it, or is there a way to actually pass methods?

Comment: you can use the class like a class variable in these classes and then depending upon need you can initialize the class and reuse their methods

Comment: `A a = new A();` then `B b = new B(a);` Is perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you mean something like `B b = new B(this);`?

Comment: Yes, and yes... Your question is rather basic Java knowledge. You can simply define a constructor `B(A aInstance)` to pass `A` in, or you could pass in a method handle or lambda (Java 8). if you only want it to access a specific method, etc.

Comment: May be non-static inner class fits better that passing this to constructor?

Comment: Yes, something like B b = new B(this); but in this case 'this' somehow refers to the ClickListener instead of the whole class, and that is the main problem which led me here..

Comment: @TobiasKuess name it as `A.this` in this case if you´re within the scope of an anonymous class there.

Comment: Oh.. well that seemed easy @SomeJavaGuy, can you explain why a simple 'this' did not work?

Comment: @TobiasKuess if you´re within an inner class your `this` refers to exactly this inner class. By including the `A.this` your going to refer to the `A` instance which is bound to this inner class. You´re basicly just making `this` have the scope of `A` instead of your Listener

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do it is by creating an Interface with function that are required to be call by class B, and implement this Interface via class A. Now, when creating an instance of class B inside class A, pass the reference of class A object to class B through constructor.
e.g.

```
interface IA{
void foo();
}

class B{
    IA aInstance;
    public B(IA temp){
        aInstance = temp;
    }
    //call function of A from anywhere like inside this function
    void function(){
        aInstance.foo();
    }
}
class A implement IA{
    B bInstance;
    public A(){
        bInstance = new B(this);
    }
    void foo(){
       //Implement foo here
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.